# Form Symfony2 Many to One, showing foreign key in drop down, using collections

Tags: forms, collections, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to display a list, somehow the only way the field appears to be active if it's i don't use "collection" but i'll like to add stuff in case they don't exist. I read that's the way to do that.

```
    <?php

namespace Monse\WebBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType; use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class BasedeDatosType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nombreBD')
            ->add('ServidorBD', 'collection', array('type' => new ServidoresBDType()))
        ;
    }  public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Monse\WebBundle\Entity\BasedeDatos',
        );
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'basededatos';
    } }
```

Using this the field doesn't appear. 
Using ->add ('ServidorBD') it does, but it's not a dropdown list and i'm not using collections.

```
<?php

namespace Monse\WebBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Monse\WebBundle\Entity\BasedeDatos
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BasedeDatos
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

   /**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Monse\WebBundle\Entity\ServidoresBD")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="servidores_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
*
*/
    private $servidorBD;

    /**
     * @var string $nombreBD
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombreBD", type="string", length=255,unique=true)
     */
    private $nombreBD;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set servidorBD
     *
     * @param integer $servidorBD
     */
    public function setServidorBD(\Monse\WebBundle\Entity\ServidoresBD $servidorBD)
    {
        $this->servidorBD = $servidorBD;
    }

    /**
     * Get servidorBD
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getServidorBD()
    {
        return $this->servidorBD;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombreBD
     *
     * @param string $nombreBD
     */
    public function setNombreBD($nombreBD)
    {
        $this->nombreBD = $nombreBD;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombreBD
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNombreBD()
    {
        return $this->nombreBD;
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->servidorBD = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add servidorBD
     *
     * @param Monse\WebBundle\Entity\ServidoresBD $servidorBD
     */
    public function addServidoresBD(\Monse\WebBundle\Entity\ServidoresBD $servidorBD)
    {
        $this->servidorBD[] = $servidorBD;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to do this? (I'm sorry if it's a stupid question, i'm trying to learn how to properly use symfony2)

Comment: looking for this? http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collection allow you to add new form dynamicaly. So you need to add some javascript

into the form builder :

```
$builder
            ->add('nombreBD')
            ->add('ServidorBD', 'collection', array(
              'type' => new ServidoresBDType(),
              'allow_add' => true,
              'by_reference' => false
             ));
```

into you edit.html.twig (or view file) : 
add a button and a click event on it

```
<div id="collectionContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#addField').click(function(){
            var collectionHolder = $('#ServidorBD');
            var prototype = collectionHolder.attr('data-prototype');
            var index = $('#collectionContainer').length - 1;

            form = prototype.replace(/\$\$name\$\$/g, index);
            $('#collectionContainer').append(form);
</script>
```